# dont print out buffered content

Tags: php, .htaccess

php : view.php

```
<h1>hello world</h1>
```

php: index.php

```
require('view.php');
```

if both files are on root `mysite.com`

if I access `mysite.com/index.php` I should get '**hello world**'

if I access `mysite.com/view.php` I should get Nothing displayed.

I was looking for some .HTACCESS method but any other suggestions are welcomed :)

**Conclusion**: wish the user to not be able to see the view plain text, and only allow the `required` or `get_file_contents()` to read the files. So read the file only within server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to handle this is to have your include files that are never intended to be accessed outside the web root, where they can never be accessed via a browser.

i.e. your file structure would be:

```
www/index.php
includes/view.php
```

You can set PHP's `include_path` to include the `includes/` directory so your includes don't need to have a path explicitly in them, too.

Comment: You might be onto something here lol, might be exactly what I need :)I'll give it a go :)

Answer (score 2):

Don't print your output. Make some variable (for example:`$tmp`) with output data and print it in `index.php`

Comment: $tmp = '<h1>hello world?</h1>'; is that what you mean ?

Comment: wow, dont think you get the irony on that do you? lol, thnx for trying tho

Answer (score 0):

there is .htaccess stuff you can do

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

this isnt going to be exactly what you want, but i think if you combine this with ceejayoz's answer, it should work